# Trying move mamp to new mac

Tags: mamp

i had a Mac craash - but I was able to salvage the applications folder and jobs folder.

I need to move the old MAMP files on to the new mac and the new MAMP installation.

I copied the htdocs stuff and the Db folder over - and phpmyadmin can see the database.

yet when I go to the local:8888/ directory for the transferred site I get the following error:

```
Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: Table 'ymlddartis.mbs9i_session' doesn't exist SQL=SELECT `session_id` FROM `mbs9i_session` WHERE `session_id` = '6a99e3f7011baf6d9d29de1b7d8d69ce' LIMIT 0, 1
```

Can anyone help???

Comment: Did you transfer a backup of your database?

Comment: No, I cannot get into phpmyhadmin and export it because the mac crashed - so I cannot launch mamp on that machine to export the DB which is why I am looking for help here. All I could do was salvage those folders.

Answer (score 2):

**The error message can be misleading!** I remember I had the same issue after moving my MAMP PRO to another volume due to system issues and new OSX installation. I had several websites based on Wordpress, Joomla, and also Drupal.

If everything is in the correct location(s) and you can connect to DB tables via phpMyAdmin... it is a wrong or reset environment variable. Most likely the allocated memory in the respective **PHP.ini**

**1)** I assume you have a Joomla CMS? The table info in your error message looks like this. Then you can edit the configuration.php of your website, and turn error reporting from "default" to "1":

*public $error_reporting = '1';*

Save file and reload the website again. Any new message about "memory allocation..." ?!

**2)** If you installed a new MAMP, your default setting are too low. You have to edit the correct .INI file of your chosen PHP version! It should be located here:

Example for PHP 5.4.19

*Applications/MAMP/bin/php/**php5.4.19**/conf/**php.ini***

Edit the file and search for:

*memory_limit = 32M*

I would suggest a value of 128M instead. Save the file. Restart the server/MAMP app!!

If you use different PHP versions, you have to repeat the steps accordingly.

---

BTW, right above the memory settings are time related settings. I would suggest much higher values as well ;)